# BrowserMob only partially loading page on initial load; fine afterwards

Tags: python-2.7, selenium-webdriver, browsermob

I'm trying to use BrowserMob to proxy pages with Selenium WebDriver.  When the initial page request is made, many elements of the page fail to load (e.g., css, jquery includes).  If I manually refresh the page everything loads as expected.

Has anyone else seen this behavior?  Is there a solution?

Thanks!

Comment: Firefox shows the request being made but the files show a 0k file size and have no return code: https://www.evernote.com/shard/s30/sh/8f5daff0-89d0-43b4-9e56-07eeffb8474d/0a14e214cb5c7353e57e392e30fd616d

Answer (score 1):

When you configure the WebDriver in your test code, set the proxy address not as `localhost:8080` but as `127.0.0.1:8080`. I think that Firefox has some problems resolving the proxy `localhost:8080` that it does not have with the explicit form `127.0.0.1:8080`.

Comment: It's not true, this is exactly an answer to his question and a solution to his problem.

Comment: It works also for me, thank you Marco. @Andrew have you tested the solution?